# How to properly load a datagridview with a paginated list;

Tags: c#, datatable, datagridview, pagedlist

I am trying to load a datagridview with a paginated list but the result is as in the image shown.
However, when I populate the datagridview with the datatable from which I am converting to a pagedlist, the data is displayed correctly (unpaginated though).
Kindly help resolve this.
[The Error populated DGV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRZnA.png)

This is what i have tried:

```
IPagedList<DataRow> list;
public async void PopulateDGV(DataTable myDT)
{
    list = await GetPagedListAsync(myDT);
    myDGV.DataSource = list.ToList(); //This part populates as in the image, but when I populate it with 'myDT', it works fine
}

public async Task<IPagedList<DataRow>>GetPagedListAsync(DataTable dt, int pageNumber = 1, int pageSize = 10)
{
    return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {    
        return dt.AsEnumerable().ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
    });
}
```